# How do I open a report in SSRS 2008 without the user having to provide authentication details?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Summary:
Does anyone know what the minimum we have to do is to get the user to be able to press a button in our app and have the report pop up in an HTML control (Delphi App) with no further input from the user?

Detail:
Authentication is no longer anything to do with IIS in 2008, and a lot of authentication discussion on the web is about IIS and SSRS 2005.

We are looking to display reports within our application and are trying to avoid using the API to re-construct the ReportViewer.

We are hoping to open the reports within an HTML control by passing a URL to the control, along the lines of http://RSServer/ReportServer/ReportDir/ReportName.....

This doesn't work and it looks like it is because the report asks for authentication. We use SQL server authentication for the rest of the app and explicitly want our app installable where domain authentication is patchy at best.

I have enabled Basic authentication which doesn't make much difference, but you don't seem to be able to anable Anonymous Auth, which wouldn't actually be desirable anyway.

Dom.

Comment: Dumb question - with basic auth switched on, can you use a URL login - http://username:password@rsserver/....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried it, but have you looked at [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx)?

**EDIT**

[This may be of more use](http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoftbob/archive/2009/08/20/a-wrapper-for-running-sql-server-2008-reporting-services-reports-anonymously.aspx) - it suggests a method of bypassing authentication without running anonymous access

**EDIT 2**
With basic authorisation enabled, could you simply provide credentials in the URL? - http://username:password@servername/etc/etc?

Comment: That looks really good, but we hope to keep some security. If that is not possible then the anon might have to be put forward as an option.

Comment: Oh my god, they should just make SSRS use SQL authentication: Thanks for finding this, time to  get a coffee and have a read.

Comment: I think the problem with providing them in the url is that the verification of the credentials is still done via Windows Authentication, and if that worked, we wouldn't have a problem in the first place!

Comment: Sorry, to be clearer, we don't want to have to depend on our customers setting up their Windows servers correctly so when we pass a user/password combo, it actually works.